# Different behaviour when running code in junit

Tags: java, spring, ant, junit

currently i am developing a spring app.  Until now i used Ant and Junit for running the code. Now i tried to move the test code to a java class and run it also from Ant with the java task, which fails due to the following exception:

```
 [java] javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl not found
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecuteJava.execute(ExecuteJava.java:194)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.run(Java.java:764)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.executeJava(Java.java:218)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.executeJava(Java.java:132)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.execute(Java.java:105)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
 [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 [java]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 [java]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:357)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:385)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1337)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1306)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1189)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:758)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:257)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:104)
 [java] Caused by: javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl not found
 [java]     at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(DocumentBuilderFactory.java:129)
 [java]     at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:849)
 [java]     at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:773)
 [java]     at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:483)
 [java]     at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:127)
 [java]     at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:73)
 [java]     at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:242)
 [java]     at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:156)
 [java]     at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:132)
 [java]     at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:645)
 [java]     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractApplicationContext.java:160)
 [java]     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:89)
 [java]     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext.java:59)
 [java]     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:61)
 [java]     at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:136)
 [java]     at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
 [java]     at org.postslurper.Main.init(Unknown Source)
 [java]     at org.postslurper.Main.<init>(Unknown Source)
 [java]     at org.postslurper.Main.main(Unknown Source)
 [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 [java]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 [java]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecuteJava.run(ExecuteJava.java:217)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecuteJava.execute(ExecuteJava.java:152)
 [java]     ... 21 more
 [java] --- Nested Exception ---
 [java] javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl not found
 [java]     at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(DocumentBuilderFactory.java:129)
 [java]     at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:849)
 [java]     at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:773)
 [java]     at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:483)
 [java]     at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:127)
 [java]     at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:73)
 [java]     at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:242)
 [java]     at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:156)
 [java]     at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:132)
 [java]     at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:645)
 [java]     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractApplicationContext.java:160)
 [java]     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:89)
 [java]     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext.java:59)
 [java]     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:61)
 [java]     at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:136)
 [java]     at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
 [java]     at org.postslurper.Main.init(Unknown Source)
 [java]     at org.postslurper.Main.<init>(Unknown Source)
 [java]     at org.postslurper.Main.main(Unknown Source)
 [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 [java]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 [java]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecuteJava.run(ExecuteJava.java:217)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecuteJava.execute(ExecuteJava.java:152)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.run(Java.java:764)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.executeJava(Java.java:218)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.executeJava(Java.java:132)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.execute(Java.java:105)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
 [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 [java]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 [java]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:357)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:385)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1337)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1306)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1189)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:758)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:257)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:104)
 [java] Java Result: -1
```

This exception is thrown when executing the following line, which is the main logic, both the test code and the java class contain.

```
context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("services.xml");
```

The following snippet shows, how both processes are started from ant. Both targets use the same classpath.

```
<target name="collect">
    <java classname="my.project.Main" classpathref="master-classpath">
    </java>
</target>

<target name="test">
    <property name="result.ext" value=".log"></property>
    <junit>
        <classpath refid="master-classpath"></classpath>
        <test name="my.project.test.TestMain" todir="out" outfile="dump">
            <formatter type="plain" extension="${result.ext}"/>
        </test>
    </junit>
    <fail if="test.trace">${test.trace}</fail>
</target>
```

I also dumped the jvm's properties (System.getproperties()):

```
java.runtime.name: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
sun.boot.library.path: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.20/jre/lib/amd64
java.vm.version: 16.3-b01
ant.library.dir: /usr/share/ant/lib
java.vm.vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
java.vendor.url: http://java.sun.com/
path.separator: :
java.vm.name: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
file.encoding.pkg: sun.io
user.country: DE
sun.java.launcher: SUN_STANDARD
sun.os.patch.level: unknown
java.vm.specification.name: Java Virtual Machine Specification
user.dir: /home/some-desktop/hm-repo/ssb-dev/trunk
java.runtime.version: 1.6.0_20-b02
java.awt.graphicsenv: sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment
java.endorsed.dirs: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.20/jre/lib/endorsed
os.arch: amd64
java.io.tmpdir: /tmp
line.separator: 

java.vm.specification.vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
os.name: Linux
ant.home: /usr/share/ant
sun.jnu.encoding: UTF-8
java.library.path: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.20/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.20/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.20/jre/../lib/amd64:/home/some-desktop/Dev/web2test/web2test-1.3/bin/:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
java.specification.name: Java Platform API Specification
java.class.version: 50.0
sun.management.compiler: HotSpot 64-Bit Server Compiler
os.version: 2.6.32-24-generic
user.home: /home/some-desktop
user.timezone: 
java.awt.printerjob: sun.print.PSPrinterJob
file.encoding: UTF-8
java.specification.version: 1.6
java.class.path: /usr/share/ant/lib/ant-launcher.jar:/usr/share/java/xmlParserAPIs.jar:/usr/share/java/xercesImpl.jar:/home/some-desktop/.ant/lib/ivy.jar:/home/some-desktop/.ant/lib/jsch.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-apache-resolver.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-apache-bcel.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-nodeps.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-swing.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-apache-oro.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-launcher.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-commons-logging.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-jsch.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-jdepend.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-javamail.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-antlr.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-commons-net.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-apache-log4j.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-apache-bsf.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-junit.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-trax.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/junit.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-apache-regexp.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-jmf.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.20/lib/tools.jar
user.name: some-desktop
java.vm.specification.version: 1.0
java.home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.20/jre
sun.arch.data.model: 64
user.language: de
java.specification.vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
java.vm.info: mixed mode
java.version: 1.6.0_20
java.ext.dirs: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.20/jre/lib/ext:/usr/java/packages/lib/ext
sun.boot.class.path: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.20/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.20/jre/lib/rt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.20/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.20/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.20/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.20/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.20/jre/classes
java.vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
file.separator: /
java.vendor.url.bug: http://java.sun.com/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi
sun.io.unicode.encoding: UnicodeLittle
sun.cpu.endian: little
sun.cpu.isalist:
```

I also computed a diff of the java properties and the only line that is different in Junit is

```
user.timezone: Europe/Berlin
```

Does anybody have an idea, what is wrong?

Cheers,

GLA

Comment: Both tasks (`java` and `junit`) run in the same JVM and same environment as ant unless `fork="true"` is set on the tasks. Try running them with fork set to true to be less dependant on the ant environment.

Comment: Thank you @JB, it works now! Still, i can't figure out, why the issue with this xml parser arouse with java. Is somebody there, who could provide me with some backround information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is difficult to say exactly why you're having this problem, but it will be as JB Nizet says something to do with the classpath that is being inherited from ant. You'll notice that your error is from log4j/slf4j deep within spring.

When you launch junit from ant with fork="false" it uses the classpath defined by ant, which may include all sorts of dependencies, including different versions of log4j which depend upon different versions of xerces.

When you fork, you have a much cleaner environment, so it works.

To avoid this sort of problem, it's generally a good idea to fork your junit tests to avoid dragging all these dependencies into your project. Not forking can cause other problems further down the line.

See [Ant Junit Task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html) for more options.

Comment: Ok, there is no need to dig further into it, i'll just use the fork option. Thank you for your answer.